# How to make the non visible part of a Gallery to be null

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have used gallery widget to display downloaded images.But unfortunately I am running into out of memory situation. So I am trying to null the invisible part of the gallery so that I can save my memory. Is it possible to hide the non visible parts of the gallery.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory Issues is not because of `Gallery`, its because of adapter I guess that you are using Gallery itself use concept of `recycling` `views` that are non visible so its not responsible for **out of memory**.

What I think is you are creating an adapter of bitmaps and that is what causing errors.